# I need to drag outside of the calendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I have multiple calendars side by side, if you understand.

I need to drag an event from one calendar to another.

It seems I cant drag an event outside the bounds of its calendar. Why is this so, as I should be able to drag an event anywhere, its the dropping of it which is important.

Comment: Have you tried setting `droppable` attribute? http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs2/dropping/droppable/ Please provide some code and what you have tried.

Answer (score -1):

Which system are you on? Many calendar applications do not allow you to do so...